# How to get the declaring member of implementing one?

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes, postsharp

I am working with PostSharp and I cannot figure out how to get to declaring member (in my case it is method). Say I would like to write some custom null validation for arguments (using `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`) and I would like to apply my aspect right on the interface level.

When I do this when, and `OnEntry` is triggered:

```
public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    args.Method...?
}
```

I get the implemented method (the one which was actually called) but I need the "original", declaring one. For example:

```
class Speaker : ISpeaker
{
    public string Say(); // I get access to this method...
}

interface ISpeaker
{
    [MyCustomAspect]
    string Say();  // ... and I need to get this one
}
```

It seems that using reflection I can get only to first implementation, not declaration. And on the other hand attribute or Postsharp aspect do no keep any information for which member they were applied (at least I didn't find it).

So how to get to it?

*For the record, I need to apply aspects at interface level, it is a must.*

Comment: Try the `Type.GetInterfaceMap` method on `typeof(Speaker)`.

Comment: Bear in mind that it's perfectly possible to have a single method be the implementation for *several* interface members, if the class is implementing multiple interfaces and some of the methods are compatible (same signatures)

Comment: Yeah. It is even possible that an inherited and not overridden method (and thus invisible in your code) implements an interface.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, it is out of scope here, but do you have EII in mind? They are visible though.

Comment: @thehennyy, thank you, with that information I found a close question so I voted to close mine. Anyway, this works like a charm!